# Como passar parâmetros em eventos no React?

Tags: javascript, react

Assumindo o código abaixo (linha **15**):

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

function App() {
  function handleClick(item) {
    alert(`Você clicou no item ${item}!`)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {items.map((item) => (
        // Note na linha abaixo, em que uso uma arrow function:
        <button key={item} onClick={() => handleClick(item)}>
          Item {item}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Note que eu preciso passar um argumento para o meu *handler* de evento (conforme fiz na linha 15). Para isso, usei uma *arrow function*, que chama a função `handleClick`, passando o argumento desejado (no exemplo, `item`).

Atualmente, sei que existem duas formas de se fazer isso:

- Usando *arrow functions*, como mostrado no exemplo acima (`{() => eventHandler(...args)}`);
- Usando `Function.prototype.bind` (`{this.handleClick.bind(this, ...args)}`).

No entanto, de acordo com a documentação, essas duas opções criam uma **nova função a cada renderização**, o que pode afetar a performance em certos casos.

ℹ️ Esses avisos podem ser vistos [aqui](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#bind-in-render) e [aqui](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render).

Então, a pergunta é: assumindo que realmente **seja necessário passar um argumento do `render`**, há alguma forma de fazê-lo sem after a performance (já que a documentação do React só cita os dois exemplos)?

Comment: A documentação cita uma alternativa, que é utilizar [data-attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#example-passing-params-using-data-attributes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa criar outro componente e passar o item como props:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

class MyButton extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    function handleClick() {
        alert(`Você clicou no item ${this.props.item}!`)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                Item {this.props.item}
            </button>
        );
    }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <MyButton item={item} />
      ))}
    <div/>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```